# Custom resharper file-template moved to different layer doesn't show up anymore

Tags: resharper-6.0

Previously I created a custom resharper file template to create a new test class.
This template worked just fine.

I decided to move it to a separate layer and exported it so I could share it in my team. 
After importing it, the template shows up in the template explorer, but it is not available in the solution explorer.

Furthermore it doesn't show up on my own machine either anymore.

What am I missing?